# Using parent method in child class | python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, parent-child

Just learning Python, don't be mad.

Consider the following code:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def print_hello():
        print "hello"

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()    

    @staticmethod
    def print_all():
        print_hello()
        print "world"
```

Question is why can't I call parent's `print_hello()` in a child method, if I inherit it?

Comment: If you want to call a method, you need to explicitly specify what object you're calling the method of. It has to be `something.print_hello()`, not just `print_hello()`. Now, figure out what the `something` should be.

Comment: Also, if you're on Python 2, `Parent` should explicitly inherit from `object` if it doesn't inherit from anything else.

Comment: `Child.print_hello()` works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Child.print_hello()` works.

Question is closed.